# Getting error in printing elements of array in reverse.- java

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone find the error in the program.
i want to print the elements of an array in reverse manner by i am getting error after execution of program can anyone help me.?

```
int i,n;
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter range- ");
n=in.nextInt();
int ar[] = new int[n];
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
   i=in.nextInt();
   ar[i]=in.nextInt();
}
for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
{
  System.out.print("Enter elements" +ar[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the error? Does that error(or exception) tell anything? Have tried debugging?

Comment: There is no `n` element in an `n` dimension array. Only up to `n-1`.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=n;i++)` should be `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)`, otherwise you'll get an ArrayOutOfBounds exception

Comment: `Can anyone find the error in the program` Is it a need game on SO ? _Find the error_

Comment: @VeeraKannadiga  array out of bound

Answer (score 1):

`i` is your loop variable, don't modify `i` in the loop (with user input). Also, arrays start at `0` (not `1`). So,

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   // i=in.nextInt();
   ar[i]=in.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Entered elements");
for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
{
  System.out.print(ar[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: and the condition of the first loop is `i<n` not `i<=n` (you corrected it but not mention it ;) ) because there is no `n` cell in  array of length `n`

Answer (score 0):

you have some mistakes in your program :

first you dont have to declare `i` at begining of program only in for loop

second  you assign `i` value to user input in each iteration of for loop `i=in.nextInt();`

and you put at for loop `i <= n` it will assign additional element to the array more than the required size.

also in for loop that print values of array in reverse order it will not print the first index value of array because you put condition `i > 0;`

```
int n;
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter range- ");
n=in.nextInt();
int ar[] = new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   ar[i]=in.nextInt();
}
for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
{
  System.out.print("Enter elements" +ar[i]);
}
```

Comment: that ok i will do it